# Getting 'global' variables from other jsp pages?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Can a variable declared in one jsp file be used in another, if imported? Example:

```
// index.jsp
<%
int count = 40;
%>

<%@include file='go.jsp'%><%


// go.jsp
<%
count += 10;
%>
```

is count visible to go.jsp? I am guessing this is not good design anyway (expecting global variables to be around for you from another page), just wondering if this can work while I prototype.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Your JSP is compiled to a servlet, whose `doGet(..)` method contains the code of all included pages.

If you want something like that, you'd better place the variable in the page context - `pageContext.setAttribute("attrName", value);` and then retrieve it with the corresponding method.

If using JSTL, you can do this by using `<c:set var="varName" value="yourValue" />` and then use the variable in JSTL expressions: `${varName}`